# FreeBSD aliased user identification and GNU screen

Tags: freebsd, gnu-screen, environment-variables, user-accounts

The situation is the following.

1. I have FreeBSD user `M`, which is an alias for `root`, i.e., its UID equals to 0.
2. I have a daemon started as `M` (as a shell for an autologin console, if it matters).
3. The daemon should start `screen` non-interactively. And it actually does, but here's the quirk: `screen` also starts as `M`, thus its socket file is placed to `/tmp/screens/M`, not `/tmp/screens/root` where I actually need it to be able to attach as root while still leaving `screen` in single-user mode).

I've tried the following without success:

```
USER=root /usr/local/bin/screen ...
```

and

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/screen ...
```

How does it detect the actual username? How can I force it to think it's really `root` and not `M`?

Comment: @ChrisS: So that I could have the daemon launched by init as a "getty shell", and respawned in case it fails.. Were it some kind of, say, Ubuntu, I'd just added the daemon to `inittab` flagged with `respawn`.

Comment: @ChrisS: Exactly. If I do it for root, I'm going to have to set the daemon as the root shell (or is there some other facility to launch it instead of getty?). But then I'll be unable to login as root, which is an interesting situation =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looking through the sources of `screen`, I've found that it utilises POSIX function `getlogin()` to get the session login. It is not, generally, stored in a variable. BUT there exists the complementary function `setlogin()`, which does the trick (at least for me on FreeBSD8.2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        char * l = getlogin();
        printf("Current login: %s\n", l ? l : "(NULL)");
    }
    else
    {
        int s = setlogin(argv[1]);
        printf("setlogin(\"%s\") returned %d\n", argv[1], s);
        if (s) perror("setlogin");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Surely, for `setlogin()` to succeed, it must be run with the superuser privileges.